# Drawing of a surface

Tags: analytic-geometry

Does anyone know what is the drawing of the surface with equal: $xy=a$ and $zw=b$ where $(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb R^4$ and $a,b \in \mathbb R$? I thought that it is something like an excessive cylinder but i am not sure.